# I want to deduce recipes from commercial food packaging

Tags: windows, linux, open-source, osx

I happen to have a jar of curry paste with these ingredients.

[image]

...and this nutrition:

[image]

In the UK, ingredients have to be listed in order of weight. So at a glance I know, for example that (per 100g):

- that there is less than 6g of Turmeric.
- there is less than 5g salt because otherwise the nutrition would be off.
- that there's about 63g of water (unaccounted for weight in the nutrition)
- that there is less than 2g of funnel of cloves (because 'spices' has to be <2g by UK rules)

Thus that there's less then 13g of rapeseed oil, and thus that the rest of the fat has to come from the spices in varying amounts.

I think there is enought information on the packets to do a really good reverse engineering of the actual amounts (with upper and lower bounds obviously) and I'm looking for software to do it.

It feels like something that is *very* software friendly, and that a reasonble constraint satisfier would have little or no problem with.  Where can I find such a thing?

There are, obviously, lots of reasons that software WON'T give you 'great' answers for this, including:

- Foods can change nutrition under heat and we don't know about how much the ingredients are heated
- A receipe is more than just the amounts
- Most of the information is sort of obvious (obviously you'd have less than 2g of cloves because otherwise they'd be overpowering)

...but I do think that I'd get *quite* good answers, and they'd certainly be better than me guessing by looking at the back of the packet.

Comment: I wouldn't wonder if there's an Android/iPhone app letting you make photos of the two sides, uploading them to some server for processing, and returning the answer to you – though I haven't seen it yet. I have some [food scanners in my lists](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/health_food_ingredients) but didn't try them; so if Android apps would be acceptable, you might wish to have a look.

Comment: Frame challenge. With a curry, the precise measure of the ingredients is far less important than the method… that's one reason those jars never taste like a take-away, they load them with vinegar for starters. You can go through 20 dedicated curry recipe books & *still* not manage to make a good one. [I have no formal culinary training, so without that, it took me 20 years to learn how to make a curry like I could buy in any 'indian' in Bradford.]